# VBA Loop to target certain cells based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to achieve a macro where it loops through Column D and based on its value i want it to color in certain multiple cells on that specific row where the value exists. This needs to happen for each row where it meets a certain criteria but i can only seem to get it to work when the active cell has been selected not an automated process. Here is what i have so far:

```
Sub Validate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("D4:D1000")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "Building Blocks" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 7

    ElseIf cell.Value = "Test" Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Three things: 1. Is the sheet you want this to work for active when you fire the macro? If you just use `Range("D4:D1000")` it assumes `Activesheet` is the sheet you mean. 2. If your cells say, for example, "Building Blocks ", it will register as false, so you might need to do a Trim. 3. Finally, have you opened up your macro and gone through it step by step by pushing F8, hovering your mouse over `cell.value` after the next line after `If cell.value` is highlighted, to make sure the cell.value is what you expect?

Comment: thank you for commenting back.

Comment: The line ActiveCell.Offset is using a different cell than the ones in your range. Use the cell variable you have set

Comment: 1. The sheet will be active when the macro is fired. 2. I am not sure what you mean by a Trim? 3. I just have and it seems to be bringing back "Test". Apologies i havent been studying VB for too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to rewrite your code for you, so I just made a few changes to yours:

```
Sub Validate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim counter As Long

Set rng = Range("D4:D1000")
Range("D4").Select

For Each cell In rng


If cell.Value = "Building Blocks" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(counter, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 7



ElseIf cell.Value = "Test" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(counter, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


End If
counter = counter + 1

Next
End Sub
```

An even better way as noted by 3-14159265358979323846, would be to just take your original code and change Activecell to Cell:

Sub Validate()

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range


Set rng = Range("D4:D1000")


For Each cell In rng


If cell.Value = "Building Blocks" Then
    cell.Offset(, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 7



ElseIf cell.Value = "Test" Then
    cell.Offset(, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


End If


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of `cell` in that code? :0) I mean, surely `ActiveCell` should be replaced by `cell` as per my answer!

Comment: I was just using the code that he provided.  All I did was just add a "counter" and make sure D4 was actually selected before he ran the code.  Of course if I was writing it from scratch I personally would of done it different. Case Statement, not selecting cells at all, etc.

Comment: @rwilson That was really useful, thankyou very much i understand now. I know where i went wrong.

Comment: Fair comment. But surely using the `ActiveCell` as a basis for the offset is going to produce different results depending on what row is selected when the macro is run?

Comment: Exactly, which is why I added Range("D4").Select to the code.

Comment: Lol. Hadn't noticed that ... I was just thrown by the fact that `cell` takes the value of each cell in `rng` and therefore `ActiveCell` and `counter` are not needed. I guess the OP's approach is down to personal choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the `ActiveCell` in the following line ...

```
ActiveCell.Offset(, 16).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
```

What you really want is ...

```
cell.Offset(, 16).Interior.ColorIndex =7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. This will go through column D, If it finds Building Blocks, it will look in that row, for a second Building Blocks. If it finds it, it will color the cell in colorindex 7. Same idea with find. Not tested.

```
Sub Validate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("D4:D1000")


For Each cell In rng


If cell.Value = "Building Blocks" Then
    for i = 2 to 50 'Howverlong your row is, could go to the end too if dynamic
        if cell(,i).value = cell.value then cell(,i).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
    next



ElseIf cell.Value = "Test" Then
    for i = 2 to 50 'Howverlong your row is, could go to the end too if dynamic
        if cell(,i).value = cell.value then cell(,i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4        
    next


End If

Next
End Sub
```